# Append text to lines between two patterns every time they appear in a file

Tags: command-line, bash, regex, sed

This will be a rather hard one, i guess.

I have to fiddle around with inline documentation that is extracted into html files to be used as online documentation, but these parts of the files should be without html 
 tags in the inline form, but only on the extracted html files. However, since these documentation parts are also extracted into a .wiki file, some tags are already there like this.

```
this is some text describing what is done
<code>
here are 
some line that will be shown as code in wiki 
but not on html cause they are shown on one line
in html output
</code>

some more describing text
<code>
another piece of code 
that shows up as multiple lines in the wiki
but not in htmls
</code>
```

After the extraction of these parts of the documentation which is easily done via sed, I want to sed the extracted file to this:

```
this is some text describing what is done
<code><br/>
here are <br/>
some line that will be shown as code in wiki <br/>
but not on html cause they are shown on one line<br/>
in html output<br/>
</code><br/>

some more describing text
<code><br/>
another piece of code <br/>
that shows up as multiple lines in the wiki<br/>
but not in htmls<br/>
</code><br/>
```

What I got so far is this sed line:

```
sed -i '/\<code>/,/\<\/code>/{s/$/\<br\/>/}' file
```

but it appends the html-tags also to the text between the code areas like this:

```
this is some text describing what is done
<code><br/>
here are <br/>
some line that will be shown as code in wiki <br/>
but not on html cause they are shown on one line<br/>
in html output<br/>
</code><br/>
<br/>
some more describing text<br/>
<code><br/>
another piece of code <br/>
that shows up as multiple lines in the wiki<br/>
but not in htmls<br/>
</code><br/>
```

This is basically corret, because sed appends to all lines between the first  `and the last`  tag, but it is not what I intended.

Can someone give me a hint on what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect backslashes.  The expression `\<` does *not* match a literal left broket -- an unescaped `<` matches itself just fine, but with the backslash, you change it into a left word boundary zero-width assertion, which can never happen next to a slash; so the expression `\</code>` can never match anything.

With some minor refactoring to also fix other merely superfluous hypercorrectness, a fixed `sed` script is

```
sed -i '/<code>/,\%</code>%s:$:<br/>:' file
```

I took the liberty to change the slashes to something else to remove the need for backslashes even further.

Demo: http://ideone.com/feVWgO

Comment: This one is really great, thank you for this. Could you please explain the "%s:$:<br/>:" part, as this seems to be the working part?

Comment: You are parsing it wrong.  The general syntax is *address* followed by *command*.  The *address* in this case is a range from `<code>` (quoted with slashes) to `</code>` (quoted with percent signs, with a backslash in front to change the quote delimiter) and the *command* is `s:$:<br/>:` which replaces `$` (which is a placeholder which matches at end of line) with `<br/>`, using colons as regex delimiters.  The real beef here is changing the end of the range regex so that it correctly matches `</code>` literally. The rest of my changes are sugaring to avoid having to use so many backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

OK, found a solution, although not with `sed`, but with `awk`.

```
awk '
  BEGIN{c=0} // initialize variable with zero
  /\<code>/{c=1} // if start pattern found set variable to 1
  {if (c==1) print $0,"<br/>"} // if variable is one, append tag
  {if (c==0) print $0} // if variable is zero just print line
  /\<\/code>/{c=0} //if endpattern is found set variable to zero
  '
```

This is actually quite simple but elegant.